# Input dimension mismatch in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, time-series, lstm

Hi Can anyone help me out with the error, I have seemed to search through the documentation but to no avail.

The aim is to predict a time series. I have used a dummy data `shape = (N, timesteps, features)`. I wish to `predict x_2` from `x_1, x_3` from `x_2` and so on till `x_11` from `x_10` using `LSTM`. (Any suggestion to do it better is welcome). The output (below) shows the expected output shapes which seem correct. However, the error mentions an input dimension mismatch. As per documentation, I can't seem to find the problem.

```
import numpy as np

N = 13*12;
T = 10;
F = 3;
X = np.random.rand(N, T, F);
Y = np.random.rand(N, 1, F);
Y = np.concatenate((X[:,1:T,:], Y), axis=1);

import keras

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Lambda, concatenate, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from keras import regularizers
from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
from keras.models import load_model


input_ = Input(shape = (T, F), name ='input');
x = Dense(15, activation='sigmoid', name='fc1')(input_);
x = LSTM(25, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh', name='lstm')(x);
x = Dense(F, activation='sigmoid', name='fc2')(x);

model = Model(input_, x, name='dummy');

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy']);

print(model.input_shape); print(X.shape);
print(model.output_shape); print(Y.shape);

print(model.summary());

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size = 13, epochs=30, validation_split=0.20, shuffle=False);
```

The error comes as

```
Using Theano backend.
(None, 10, 3)
(156, 10, 3)
(None, 10, 3)
(156, 10, 3)
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           (None, 10, 3)             0
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 10, 15)            60
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 10, 25)            4100
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 10, 3)             78
=================================================================
Total params: 4,238
Trainable params: 4,238
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 124 samples, validate on 32 samples
Epoch 1/30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 903, in __call__
    self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 10, input[1].shape[1] = 15)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 34, in <module>
    model.fit(X, Y, batch_size = 13, epochs=30, validation_split=0.20, shuffle=False);
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1498, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1152, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 1158, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 917, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 903, in __call__
    self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 10, input[1].shape[1] = 15)
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)](Reshape{3}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0,x}.0)
Toposort index: 98
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, (True, False, True))]
Inputs shapes: [(13, 10, 15), (1, 15, 1)]
Inputs strides: [(600, 60, 4), (60, 4, 4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Reshape{2}(Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0, TensorConstant{[-1 15]}), Elemwise{Composite{((i0 + i1 + i2
+ i3) * scalar_sigmoid(i4) * (i5 - scalar_sigmoid(i4)))}}[(0, 0)](Reshape{3}.0, Reshape{3}.0, Reshape{3}.0, Reshape
{3}.0, Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)].0, TensorConstant{(1, 1, 1) of 1.0})]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created.
This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizati
ons can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

I am unable to understand the error as to why the input shape would be (1,15,1) in the error and what are the 2 inputs which theano mentions?

The theano version I use is 0.9.0 and keras version is 2.0.4. If I rather use no features(F), the code runs smoothly.

**Edit 1**: batch size is 13, just for clarity in error log. Removing it also gives the exact same error.

Comment: What is your `Y` shape?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue - your code runs OK here (with Tensorflow backend), and I guess it is not a matter of libraries version etc. Most probably, you have accidentally changed your `X` variable somewhere; start a fresh session, run the exact code you shown, and you should be fine